# TypeScript で連想配列の中身の型を引っ張り出して使いたい

Tags: javascript, typescript

連想配列の内部の階層の型を引っ張ってくる方法を教えていただきたいです。

```
type Outside = {
  key: {
    a: number;
    b: string;
  }
}

// Outside型のkeyからInside型を作りたい （Outside型は変更してはいけない）
// type Inside = typeof Outside.key // 'Outside' は型のみを参照しますが、ここで値として使用されています。 ts(2693)

const v: Inside = getOutsideValue().key;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

型の要素に`[]`でアクセスできます。機能としては[Indexed Access Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html)と呼ばれてるようです。

```ts
type Inside = Outside["key"];
```